# Link_to remote:true not rendering a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, link-to-remote

Trying to get a flash message and render a partial on an ajax call with link_to and `remote:true`

I have in my controller examples.rb:

```
def create

    * Some stuff happens *


    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html do 
            flash[:notice] = "Works!"
            redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
        end
    end
end
```

I have the "**link_to**" form in   _one_partial.html.erb

```
<%= link_to examples_path(whatever: locals[:whatever]), class: "whatever", method: :post, remote: true do %>
  <div class="whatever_vix">
    <p> Click Here! </p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

which is in a view as:

```
<div id="addhere">
    <%= render 'favorites/one_partial', locals: {whatever: @whatever} %>
</div>
```

and in create.js.erb

```
$('#addhere').append("<%= j render 'whatever/another_partial' %>")
```

The ** some stuff happens ** part in my controller obviously works, but the new partial in **create.js.erb** doesn't show, neither the flash message appears once I add `remote:true` to the **"link_to"** form

Comment: The flash message is not showing because, you have added flash message only in js response and not in html response. When remote true is set, the response expected is js type, hence there is no flash message set. Can you confirm there is no console errors, when create,js.erb is rendered?

Comment: Even if I add:

```        respond_to do |format|
            format.js do
                flash[:notice] = "#{@room.listing_name.capitalize} added to favorites"
                redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
            end
            format.html do 
                flash[:notice] = "#{@room.listing_name.capitalize} added to favorites"
                redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
            end
        end
```

in that case, the page still refreshes and no flash message is shown

Comment: No errors are shown related to create.js,erb

Comment: `format.js{ flash.now[:notice] = "Works!"}` - Can you try something like this, not tested though.
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#flash-now

Comment: Adding that doesn't show the flash message and the page remains static (although the action executes)